# Can android:list be used twice in the same application? (separate Activities)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor

I've got an application that lists items from SQLite in two different places in order to populate listviews.  I'm using identical code in both places (adjusting for table and field names, of course), but only the first listview populates with data.  If I switch the table/field names between the two activities, I the first one populates properly with the data that's not populating in the second activity.  I'm wondering if @+id/android:list gets reserved or something in the first activity, disallowing it from being populated in the second activity.

I have logged the cursor data in the second activity to ensure that I'm actually getting data in the cursor and I am.  I'm not getting any exceptions or relevant messages of any kind in Logcat for the ListView that doesn't populate.  When I swapped the table/field names, the data that was originally getting populated to the first listview likewise does not get populated to the second listview.  The only thing I can figure is that @+id/android:list is volatile and can only be used once per application.  Is this correct or is there a detail that I'm missing?

FIRST ACTIVITY:

```
private static final String fields[] = { "firstfield1", "firstfield2",  "_id" };
...
final CursorAdapter dataSource;
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = database.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) firsttable", null);
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.moveToFirst();                       // Always one row returned.
        if (cur.getInt (0) == 0) {               // Zero count means empty table.

        } else {
            Cursor data = database.query("firsttable", fields, null, null, null, null, null);
            dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowcolumns, data, fields, new int[] { R.id.firstfield1, R.id.firstfield2});
            data.moveToFirst();

            while (data.isAfterLast() == false){
                Log.i("MyActivity", "data: "+data.getString(0));
                data.moveToNext();
            }

            final ListView view = getListView();

            setListAdapter(dataSource);
}
```

ROWCOLUMNS.XML

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/firstfield1"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="1"
     />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/firstfield2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

SECOND ACTIVITY

```
private static final String fields[] = { "secondfield1", "secondfield2",  "_id" };
...
    final CursorAdapter dataSource;
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = database.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) secondtable", null);
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.moveToFirst();                       // Always one row returned.
        if (cur.getInt (0) == 0) {               // Zero count means empty table.
            Log.i("CastrActivity", "Empty cursor");
        } else {
            Cursor data = database.query("secondtable", listFields, null, null, null, null, null);
            dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.secondcolumns, data, listFields, new int[] { R.id.secondfield1, R.id.secondfield2});
            data.moveToFirst();

            while (data.isAfterLast() == false){
                Log.i("MyActivity", "data: "+data.getString(0));
                data.moveToNext();
            }
            final ListView view = getListView();

            setListAdapter(dataSource);
}
```

SECONDCOLUMNS.XML

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/secondfield1"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="1"
     />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/secondfield2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was trying to close the cursor used by the SimpleCursorAdapter.  I was under the impression that cursors should always be closed after a certain point, but I suppose that isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, if you try to use as you described. The list you are getting is scoped to only that activities method. If you don't want to make another DB call in second activity, you may parcel the list and use it in another package.

Comment: The data that populates the second list is different than the data that populates the first list.  You make it sound like if I make another DB call in the second activity, it'll work.  That's what I'm doing and the ListView doesn't get populated.  Are you saying that I have to query the database for the second activity's listview in the first activity and then parcel that data to the second activity?

EDIT:  That doesn't make sense to me because the second list WAS getting filled up until an unknown point.  I can't track down what has changed, though.

Comment: If data is different and you are making new DB call in second activity, it should work fine. Post code related the issue.

Comment: As simple test, can you hard code same query you used in first activity to second activity and see what you are getting?

Comment: yep, already did that. i swapped out the queries and the list in the first activity populates, list in the second activity does not.

Comment: Are you sure while setContent.. you are not referring same listview xml?

Comment: Another try, comment listview in frist activity. Just keep only second activity listview, if it works, that may validate Volatile statement.

Comment: No, it still doesn't populate in the second activity.

Comment: Another try, remove SimpleCursorAdapter and hardcode array values and use arrayadapter in second activity. This should atleast display hardcoded values. I strongly suspect something wrong with this adapter.

Comment: You may be on to something.  I created an ArrayAdapter that plugged in some ArrayList values and it showed up.  Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: It is hard to figureout what is going on with SimpleCursorAdapter because of limited access to your code, work around I would suggest would be, get values from Cursor and add those values to Array and pass it it array adapter you created for testing instead of hard coded values.

Comment: The issue with that is that I'd lose the _id from the CursorAdapter, which is crucial in the next step.  There's honestly not much more to my code.  What you see is pretty much all you get, other than the onClickListener for the ListView.  I didn't think that was important, especially since it's commented at the moment.

Comment: If I compare two classes, I see only one change, dont know worth to look or not. Observation is, secondactivity defined fields[] array defined, but you passed listfileds as parameter, could that be causing anything?

Comment: No, that's the name of the array I use in the second activity to define the database fields.  Just to be thorough, I did just hardcode that array into the Adapter and got the same results, though.

Comment: Um... okay.  I just stumbled across what was causing the issue.  Closing the cursor that's accessed by the adapter causes the listview not to work.  It doesn't seem to matter where I close it, if I close it, the listview doesn't work.

Comment: Good to know. I missed it, enjoy programming.